# Node: Save generated Stripe "Customer ID" in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, stripe-payments

When a new user registers on my page, I also wanna generate a Stripe customer ID to save it, besides username and email, in the database. So far, so good. The customer creation works as I can see it in the Stripe test dashboard.

**But how can I save the Stripe response it's customer ID in a new variable for later use?**

```
stripe.customers.create({
  email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
}).then(response => {
  customerId = response.id
  });
console.log(customerId)
```

**Code update after @bharadhwaj await/async suggestion:**

```
async function stripeCustomerCreation() {
  const response = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
  })
  customerId = response.id
};
stripeCustomerCreation();
console.log(customerId)
// Create new user object and apply user input
let user = new User({
  email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
  username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
  password: req.body.password
});
```

**Update 2: Console gives me a Promise { pending }, but no customerId one line further. :(**

```
async function stripeCustomerCreation() {
  const response = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
  })
  customerId = response.id
  return customerId
};
var customerId = stripeCustomerCreation();
console.log(customerId)
```

Comment: The variable `response` is already a JSON. No need to call `reponse.json()` again!

Comment: Yes thanks, sorted this one out. But why is the customerID still undefined?

Comment: Create is an async function. You  are not waiting to finish it before reading the variable

Comment: @dmnktoe Added as an answer! Check whether it solves your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

While calling an `async` function, again you ought to add `await` in front of it to make it work. I suppose this chain of making functions `async` may keep going till everything is in `async/await` ;)

```
async function stripeCustomerCreation() {
    const response = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
    })
    customerId = response.id
    return customerId
};

const customerId = await stripeCustomerCreation();
console.log(customerId)

// Create new user object and apply user input
let user = new User({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
    username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
    password: req.body.password
});
```

---

**METHOD 2**

```
stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
}).then(response => {
    customerId = response.id
    console.log(customerId) // defined

    // Create new user object and apply user input
    let user = new User({
         email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
         username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
         password: req.body.password
    });
});
```

---

For the current code you have, we can solve it by below code.

Assigning an `async` function directly gives you a promise to resolve. Then you have to `resolve` it like the below code.

```
async function stripeCustomerCreation() {
  const response = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
  })
  customerId = response.id
  return customerId
};
stripeCustomerCreation()
  .then(customerId => {
    console.log(customerId) // Defined
  });
```

Comment: You mean at the top of the beginning, like this? "await router.post('/register', (req, res)"? :D

Comment: `async router.post(`. I feel it would be better for you to use method 2 here!

Comment: Thanks for the link. But this is kinda weird, I updated my code, so there's now a third code block.

Comment: Getting hold with `async/await` can be weird! Don't worry! Understand **Rule 0**: To call `await`, it should be inside an `async` function. I will suggest you use method 2 I have written for now.

Comment: This! Works like a charm. Thanks mate, you helped me out. Marked your answer acceptable.

Comment: Yaaay! Happy coding!

Comment: Do I have to put any further functions to async?

Comment: If there is anything asynchronous, I prefer you putting async in between and you can solve it as `Promises` or you can use `await`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188696/discussion-between-dmnktoe-and-bharadhwaj).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of async behaviour of the code.

```
// Statement 1
stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
}).then(response => {
    customerId = response.id
    // customerId is defined here
}); 

// Statement 2
console.log(customerId)
```

The order of execution of above is,

> Statement 2
>
> Statement 1

It's because the `Statement 1` is a DB operation, takes more time to finish than `Statement 2`. So `Statement 2` runs first, at that time the variable `response` is undefined. That's is why you are getting undefined.

In order for you to access the variable `customerId` correctly, we got a couple of ways:

**METHOD 1**

If you are familiar with `async/await`:

```
const response = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
})
customerId = response.id

console.log(customerId) // defined
```

Note: In order for `await` to work it should be called inside an `async` function.

---

**METHOD 2**

```
stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
}).then(response => {
    customerId = response.id
    console.log(customerId) // defined
    // Rest of your code here
});
```

Note: This can lead you to a situation called Chaining Promises. Try Googling!

---

You can choose any of this method to make it work according to your convenience.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for editing and giving some examples. I tried the async/await approach. But it's still "undefined" I'm gonna update my code.

Comment: Try method 2. Also in that, add `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` before defining customerId. It might help you!

Comment: But method 2 still defines "customer.id" only in the function itself, you told me? I have to wait for the response as you said.